# Alternative to picking from number picker when there are many alternatives

Tags: lists, datetimepicker

I am developing an app in which you have to choose 2 things.

First you pick an item from a list of 7 items:

[image]

I feel like this works very well with the "number picker" style. One reason is because when the options are alphabetical, you can rapidly reach the one you want and the "number picker" goes in a loop.

The problem is (for the ones that know about music, when picking the rest after the chord root), that the next item the user needs to choose from a list with 67 items.

[image]

The problem here is that I feel like 67 items are a bit hard to navigate using a number picker, but a list would also be too long (and ugly, sorry but I've been brainwashed to think that lists are ugly).

Do you happen to have any suggestions as to how I could represent this? What would be the best, thinking aesthetics (that it looks nice) and ease of use (the user doesn't have to scroll through a long list).

I don't know if this is necessary to mention, but there might be a 3rd screen with 80+ items, but I suppose the same applies

My only solution was to maybe put them in a huge table of buttons, but I must admit I doubt that would look pretty.

Comment: This UI requires you to C♯ or you'll B♭  --  :)

Comment: I know about music, but still fail to think what these 67 options might be. Could you please give examples?

Comment: @Izbaki {" ","m","-5","°","4","5","sus2","sus4","sus4add9","+","6","add9","add11","m6","m-6","madd9","6add9","m6add9","°7","7","7sus2","7sus4","7-5","7+5","7-9","7+9","7-5-9","7-5+9","7+5-9","7+5+9","7add11","7+11","7add13","m7","m7-5","m7-5-9","m7-9","m7add11","m(maj7)","maj7","maj7-5","maj7+5","maj7+11","9","9sus4","9-5","9+5","9+11","m9", "m9-5", "m(maj9)", "maj9", "maj9-5", "maj9+5", "maj9add6", "maj9+11", "11","11-9", "m11", "maj11", "13", "13sus4", "13-5-9", "13-9", "13+9", "13+11", "m13", "maj13"};

Comment: @DaveAlger you are right, forgot to add those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer to see 5 items at a time instead of 3 (top and bottom could be semitransparent). Perhaps "zoom" gestures could control how many items are displayed (smaller font size and faster scrolling when "zoomed out", larger font when "zoomed in")

I would be tempted to use a "quick swipe" to start rolling with inertia - it should continue to scroll by itself until I touch the display again to stop it - to speed up the process without burning my fingers.

Also all 3 choosers could be displayed on 1 screen, perhaps only 1 in black and the other 2 in gray - so horizontal swipe could switch **back** / **forwards** and vertical swipe would roll through the options of the currently selected type ("As a user, I want to see choices I made already").

If those conditions are met, I believe the number pickers could work very well.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful feedback. I will give it a try